# Multiple count based on dynamic criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two database for which I want to compare the amount of times a case appears.

TAB1:

```
ID     Sequence
A2D    1
A2D    2
A2D    3
A3D    1
```

TAB2:

```
ID     Sequence
A2D    1
A2D    2
A3D    1
A3D    2
```

Now, for this example, I am trying to get this result:

```
ID     Table1       Table2
A2D    3            2
A3D    1            2
```

I have tried these code without any success:

```
SELECT R1.ID as ID, COUNT(R1.ID) as Table1, 
COUNT(R2.ID) as Table2
FROM TAB1 AS R1, TAB2 AS R2
WHERE R1.ID = R2.ID
GROUP BY R1.ID
```

This one gave me wrong count values...

Also, this one simply crash:

```
select 
    ( 
     select count(*) as Table1
     from TAB1
     where ID = R1.ID
    ),(
      select count(*) as Table2
      from TAB2
      where ID= R1.ID
     )
FROM TAB1 AS R1
```

As you can see though, I am trying to have my criteria dynamic. Most examples I found were including basic hard-coded criteria. But for my case, I want the query to look at my first table ID, count the amount of time it appears, do it for the 2nd table with the same ID, then move on to the next ID.

If my question lacks information or is confusing just ask me, I'll do my best to be more precise.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are R1 and R2? Tables? I do not see "Builder" as a field in either table definition. Also are these tables in different databases? Or are they both tables in the same database?  You must clarify your question for us to be any real help.

Comment: Sorry, I had to change my table and fields name and data for confidentiality purpose. Builder is the "ID" in my example, I will make the corrections. Both tables are in the same Access database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am using a UNION ALL as a subquery

```
SELECT ID, SUM(T1) AS Table1, SUM(T2) AS Table2
FROM
    (SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS T1,         0 AS T2 FROM TAB1 GROUP BY ID
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ID,         0 AS T1, COUNT(ID) AS T2 FROM TAB2 GROUP BY ID)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(T1)>0 AND SUM(T2)>0
```

Comment: I am getting the right results when I look at my test cases, however Im receiving 51k results instead of the 30.7k I need from TAB1

Comment: I can't what's happening without seeing you tables. I suggest you to just query `TAB1` in order to see what happens. `SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) AS T1 FROM TAB1 GROUP BY ID`.

Comment: This return the proper result for TAB1. One thing to note however, TAB1 has 30.7k data but TAB2 has 53k. I need to get only the count for those which are in TAB1 and TAB2

Comment: I added a HAVING-clause filtering out records having zero entries either in TAB1 or in TAB2. Note: HAVING is evaluated after grouping, while WHERE is evaluated before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but you could try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, 
       (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM R1 WHERE ID = t.ID) AS table1,
       (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM R2 WHERE ID = t.ID) AS table2
FROM table1 t
```

Comment: Not sure if that would matter in a query like this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, if the data has 4 sequences but named 1,2,6,7 I want to know that there is 4 sequences. However, your query would return 7

Comment: Ahhh. your question was a little confusing. I thought you wanted max from both tables. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is actually very similar to one of your queries. The problem (I think) with your version is that you are not naming your subselects.

Comment: I think this solution looks nice! The only problem here is if Table2 contains some IDs not present in Table1 (i don't know if that could happen or not) the sums of that IDs won't appear

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach, but unfortunately I have to use two queries, i still don't know if they can be combined together. The first one is just for making sums of both tables, and combining the results:

```
SELECT "Tab1" AS [Table], Tab1.ID, Count(*) AS Total
FROM Tab1
GROUP BY "Tab1", Tab1.ID
UNION SELECT "Tab2" AS [Table], Tab2.ID, Count(*) AS Total
FROM Tab2
GROUP BY "Tab2", Tab2.ID
```

and, since Access supports Pivot queries, you can use this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(qrySums.[Total]) AS Total
SELECT qrySums.[ID]
FROM qrySums
GROUP BY qrySums.[ID]
PIVOT qrySums.[Table];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired results, I broke it down into two sub-queries (R1SQ and R2SQ) and a main UNION query - R1R2 that uses inner, left and right joins to include all row entries including those rows that do not appear in both tables:

**R1SQ**

```
SELECT R1.Builder, Count(R1.Builder) AS Table1
FROM R1
GROUP BY R1.Builder;
```

**R2SQ**

```
SELECT R2.Builder_E, Count(R2.Builder_E) AS Table2
FROM R2
GROUP BY R2.Builder_E;
```

**R1R2**

```
SELECT R1SQ.Builder, R1SQ.Table1, R2SQ.Table2
FROM R1SQ INNER JOIN R2SQ ON R1SQ.Builder = R2SQ.Builder_E
UNION
SELECT R1SQ.Builder, R1SQ.Table1, 0 AS Table2
FROM R1SQ LEFT JOIN R2SQ ON R1SQ.Builder = R2SQ.Builder_E
WHERE (((R2SQ.Builder_E) Is Null))
UNION
SELECT R2SQ.Builder_E, 0 AS Table1, R2SQ.Table2
FROM R1SQ RIGHT JOIN R2SQ ON R1SQ.Builder = R2SQ.Builder_E
WHERE (((R1SQ.Builder) Is Null))
ORDER BY R1SQ.Builder;
```